# DLRS Formula question

Tags: soql, dlrs

Okay so we have a custom object called Encounters and then we add Attendees (custom object) to the encounters. Attendees have a lookup field to contacts to connect to the what Encounter they attended. What I am trying to achieve is get a count of how many Encounters the attendees had but add the count field on the contact that is associated.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Your questions will generally be much better received if you describe more clearly what behavior you observe. Do you get an error? If so, what is the message?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use single quotes and make sure that your parentheses are balanced. You can also express this much more simply using `IN`:

```
Encounter_Subtype__c IN (
     'ANGER MANAGEMENT', 'FINANCIAL FITNESS', 'PNP', 'RECOVERY 101', 'RELAPSE PREVENTS'
)
```

DLRS relationship criteria are SOQL, not Salesforce formulas, so the [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) is where you can look for details. You're writing clauses that will be substituted by DLRS into a SOQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful.  I ran my DLRS but it is not giving me a number in my outcome field.  I am looking for the number of Encounters they have had with the SubType equaling one of the options above.  The Encounters is a custom object and then you add the Attendee (Custom Object) that attended the Encounter which Attendee is a lookup field to the Contact Object.  Here is what I have.

Comment: Janelle, would you please edit supporting details and/or a screenshot into your question?

Comment: How do I add the screenshot?

Comment: Edit your question and click the image icon on the header. It will walk you through uploading.

Comment: You need to edit your question, not post a comment. Click the edit link under your post.

Comment: I have posted my image of what I am trying to do.  Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: I'm not seeing a clear indicator of the issue. Adding a narrative of what you've done could help. And please note whether or not you deployed the DLRS trigger using the Manage Trigger button.

Comment: Okay so yes I have deployed the the trigger and it it is working but I am trying to bring in a number and it is showing that they attended not a number of how many they encounters they attended.

Comment: Janelle, I'd really love to help solve this problem, but we need you to bring the right details to your question. Could you please go back up to your question (no more comments), and write up a detailed description of exactly what steps you take, the results you expect, and the results you actually receive? Remember we cannot see your org and don't know how your data is structured, so please be very specific and explicit.